# How to parse django view object to JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

I am trying to build this :

There is a button, and if the button is clicked, it sends some request to django server and server returns some form. After that, put the form into a div.

So, my idea is

1. make a event handling function to handle button click event
2. put AJAX operation into the event handling function to send request and put a form into a div
3. Write view to receive request and return form that fits with request
4. the AJAX operation at Step 2 put returned form into the div

But the problem is, at step 3, returning form.
The form is
`form = EventForm({'date':date(year,month,day)})`

Which is a ModelForm based on the model Event.

Because Javascript cannot understand Django form object, I need something to parse it into a javascript object, like `<div>` node, or just some HTML string, but I don't know :(

I know there is `{{ form.as_p }}` for template, but I wonder whether there is such functions for python view codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With ajax, you won't be able to use django forms.

You would have to hand-craft the html form, and then use ajax to send the request to django, which would respond with a json object (most likely) which you would, again using some javascript running on the browser, be able to render on your html.